# Drawing lines/squares with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, math, drawing

I am working on a Windows application for one customer. 
He wants to be able to enter the height, width and the length of a cardboard box, and then have the application automatically draw the cardboard box on the screen.
I want to know if that's possible to be done with C#.
Here is a sample how the cardboard box should look alike:

[image]

Please let me know your opinion and if anyone else did something similar in the past. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That looks more like a label than a box to me.

Comment: Which part of the image are you referring to?  The bar codes, or the overall table-like layout?  We need better specifications!

Comment: If you cut that thing out and folded it up it'd form a box.

Comment: It looks to me like you're being asked to generate an unfolded cardboard box from the 3 dimensions. Is this the bit you're having trouble with or are you having trouble with the drawing bit?

Comment: Conrad, I want to generate an unfolded cardboard box from the 3 dimensions, yes :). Do you have any idea how I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything like that, but it's definitely possible in C#.  Looks like your box needs two sides that are width * height and two sides that are length * height, and the flaps all need to be either width / 2 or length / 2 (long / tall), whichever is shorter.  Everything you need for drawing should be in the `System.Drawing` namespace, including `Rectangle` and `Brush`.

Answer (score 0):

Some code to draw a rectangle on a Form (same works for UserControl):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);       
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)   
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Look at the other e.Graphs.Draw* methods. Combine these to make your work of art!

Answer (score -1):

Sure. You want methods in the System.Drawing namespace, coupled with the CreateGraphics() method of most Winform controls.

The basic setup is to put some control, like a Panel or a PictureBox, on your form. When it comes time to draw the box, you'll use the CreateGraphics() method of that control to get an object representing the space, the same size on screen as the control, in which you can draw. Then, you'll draw lines and/or rectangles in the proper shapes on the screen (I'll leave you the math of figuring out how the box would break down into connected cardboard panels). Look up the MSDN docs for DrawRect, and also for Brush (which you will use to determine the appearance of the lines).

EDIT: OK, I'll give you the math. For a box with length X, height Y, depth Z, the panels break down as follows:

```
 --------- ------------- --------- ------------- 
|  Zx.5Z  |    Xx.5Z    |  Zx.5Z  |    Xx.5Z    |
|---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|         |             |         |             |
|   ZxY   |     XxY     |   ZxY   |     XxY     |
|         |             |         |             |
|---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|  Zx.5Z  |    Xx.5Z    |  Zx.5Z  |    Xx.5Z    |
 --------- ------------- --------- -------------
```

Comment: This basic setup is incorrect -- you should hardly ever call `Control.CreateGraphics`, since whatever you draw will be overwritten when it is repainted.  Either: (1) Use the `Graphics` object provided to you in an event handler (e.g., `Control.Paint`, `PrintDocument.PrintPage`), or (2) Use `Graphics.FromImage` to draw on a bitmap and assign it as the image of a PictureBox.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help, it certainly will help me. @KeithS, what does .5Z means in your drawing? Thanks

Comment: Simply half the depth. Flaps on the "long" side of the box will meet at the middle if they're half the depth, and to minimize waste the flaps on the "short" side of the box are the same height.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. How do you think I can do the space between the flaps, which is used in the upper and lower part but not in the middle. Thanks

Comment: Well, each of those panels should be its own rectangle. The flap panels can simply be slightly narrower than the side to which they're attached instead of the same width like I have.